How to avoid stubtest's “[symbol] is not present at runtime” error

Example
Given the file ./mylib/minimalistic_repro.py
class Foo:
    def __init__(self, param):
        self.param = param

class Bar:
    def __init__(self, param):
        self.param = param

def foobar(par1, par2):
    return par1.param + par2.param

and its stub ./mylib/minimalistic_repro.pyi
from typing import TypeAlias

FooBar: TypeAlias = Foo | Bar

class Foo:
    param: int
    def __init__(self, param: int) -> None: ...

class Bar:
    param: int
    def __init__(self, param: int) -> None: ...

def foobar(par1: FooBar, par2: FooBar) -> int: ...

Note the type alias on the third line: FooBar: TypeAlias = Foo | Bar
mypy --strict mylib, flake8 mylib and ruff check --select E,F,B,SIM all pass.
When running stubtest however:
python -m mypy.stubtest mylib
I get the following error:
error: mylib.minimalistic_repro.FooBar is not present at runtime …

My current workaround is to use an allowlist (stubtest --generate-allowlist).

Question(s)
● Is there a “better” way to avoid this “error”? / …
● … Am I doing something fundamentally wrong? …
● … and if not: Might this be worth a feature request?

Other approaches
● Of course I could declare
 def foobar(par1: Foo | Bar, par2: Foo | Bar),
 but my actual task (writing type hints for a third party pypi package) requires a union of up to 18 types.
● I got the above example to run with stubtest by placing the FooBar type alias definition in a .py file (tp_aliases.py) and then reimporting. This approach failed to work in the case of with my actual pypi package type hinting task (tp_aliases.py is not part of the pypi package).

stubtest is complaining because it thinks your FooBar is a public API symbol, which might cause type checkers/IDE autocomplete to make incorrect assumptions and suggestions.
The "correct" way to fix it is to make it private; that is, precede the name with an underscore:
_FooBar: TypeAlias = Foo | Bar
def foobar(par1: _FooBar, par2: _FooBar) -> int: ...

For classes and functions, you can alternatively use typing.type_check_only:
# type_check_only is not available at runtime and can only be used in stubs
from typing import type_check_only

@type_check_only
def this_function_is_not_available_at_runtime() -> None: ...

@type_check_only
class AndSoDoesThisClass: ...

There's also the command line option --ignore-missing-stub which will suppress all errors of this kind.

One drawback:
Declaring, e.g. a private _FooBar: TypeAlias = Foo | Bar in module1, but only using it in module2, results in ruff and flake8 understandably complaining about “Private TypeAlias _FooBar is never used”.
I’ll address this with noqa (still way more convenient than having to work with an allowlist).

Regarding --ignore-missing-stub: Not using it allowed me to spot an issue with a class derived from a NamedTuple where stubtest complained that it was not present at runtime (solved by writing the NamedTuple with the preferred syntax for Python 3.6+).
